# "Variable not defined" when running generated script in Excel

Tags: vba, sap-gui

So, my task is to connect Excel with SAP by pulling values from a spreadsheet, inserting them into SAP form, and getting values from SAP transaction.

I assume I just need to run VBA file for that. When I run the code my spreadsheet is open and I am logged onto SAP.

The error is:

> Variable not defined

Code:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

Dim objExcel as Object
Dim objSheet as Object

Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

COL1 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Range("A1").Value)) 'Column1

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nCS15"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-MATNR").text = COL1
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-MATNR").setFocus
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what doesn't work. Does it error, or just not behave as you're expecting?

Comment: Welcome. Just remember we can't run your code or see your screen. Your question doesn't explain the actual problem. Does your code throw an error? Whats the error and what line? Does it not behave as expected? Explain what happens. Please don't write "nothing happens" or "it doesn't work".

Comment: When you say VBScript, do you mean that you're running this from a .vbs file or from a VBA procedure from inside of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for feedback. It turned out that I needed to declare SAP objects in Excel before running a script. Here is the script that works from Excel.

```
Dim Application, Connection, Session As Object
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(Session) Then
   Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

Dim objExcel As Object
Dim objSheet As Object

Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

COL1 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Range("A1").Value)) 'Column1

Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nCS15"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-MATNR").Text = COL1
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-MATNR").SetFocus
```

Comment: Feedback for your next question: post the error!!! Words like 'Does not work' and 'does not run' means absolutely nothing.

Comment: Glad you got a solution, and thanks for posting it as an answer (new contributors often just edit the question). BTW, your first 3 `IF` statements are now redundant, and you should get the same results if you delete them.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have declared `Application`and `Connection`as implicit Variant and that they are keywords.. use `Dim App as Object, Conn as Object` instead.

Comment: @DeanOC with the implicit variant declaration the Ifs just worked for Application and Connection before as they were not variant/objects, If they were declared as objects they would n't have worked too like Session, but  you should check for Is Nothing to determ if they are set to anything, if not they need to be set!

Comment: Based on your answer, I assume that you had the error "Variable not defined", probably because your VBA module had the line `Option Explicit` at the top (was not part of your excerpt). Consequently, I changed the title of the question so that it makes sense.